# Need to speed up R loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I need to speed up the nested loop below. Scores linked to item IDs are recorded by date. For each item with multiple scores, I need to relate the scores and the time distance between them. On toy data like that below, it works fine, but when the test data is replaced with data that is tens of thousands of rows, it becomes too slow to be useful. Are there better ways to do the same?

```
# create some simulated data
test <- matrix(1:18, byrow=TRUE, nrow=6)
test[,1] <- c(1,2,1,3,2,3)
test[,2] <- c(70,92,62,90,85,82)
test[,3] <- c("2019-01-01","2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01")
colnames(test) <- c("ID", "Score", "Date")
test <- data.frame(test)
test$Date <- as.Date(test$Date)

# create a dataframe to hold all the post-loop data
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0))
col_names <- c("ID", "Years", "BeginScore", "EndScore")

# get all the unique item IDs
ids <- unique(test$ID)

# loop through each unique item id
for(i in 1:length(ids))
{
   # get all the instances of that single item
   item <- test[test$ID == ids[i],]
   # create a matrix to hold the data
   scores <- data.frame(matrix(1:((nrow(item)-1)*4), byrow=TRUE, nrow=nrow(item)-1))
   colnames(scores) <- col_names
   
   # create an index, starting at the last (bc real data is ordered by data)
   index <- nrow(item)
   # loop through the list of instances of the sigle item and assign info
   for(j in 1:(nrow(item)-1))
   {
     scores$Years <- time_length(item[index,3]-item[(index -1),3], "years")
     scores$BeginScore <- item[(index-1),2]
     scores$EndScore <- item[index, 2]
     scores$ID <- item[index,1]
     index <- index - 1
   }
   # bind the single item to the collected data and then loop to next unique item
   df <- rbind(df, scores)
}
```

Comment: The real slow down in your loop is this line `df <- rbind(df, scores)`.  Dynamically growing an object is a slow process in R.  It is best to preallocate the memory prior to loop and then assign with an index to the existing data structure.

Comment: @Dave2e thank you. The other answers are useful to solve the immediate problem but I appreciate you taking the time to explain the 'why' so I can avoid it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loop is not the right tool for such operations. Also creating an empty matrix/dataframe and filling it is also very inefficient in R.

Tens of thousands of rows is not too much of data. You can try this `dplyr` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

test %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(BeginScore = nth(Score, n() - 1),
            EndScore = last(Score), 
            Years = time_length(last(Date) - nth(Date, n() - 1), 'years'))

#  ID    BeginScore EndScore Years
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
#1 1     70         62       0.999
#2 2     92         85       0.999
#3 3     90         82       0.999
```

Comment: thank you. I believe this is the right answer and is much, much faster. Is there a way to sort by date before the `summarise` statement so that I do not get negative `Years` values? I've tried the `arrange(Date)` method but it throws an error

Comment: `test %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% arrange(ID, Date) %>% group_by(ID) ...` should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table and lubridate:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(test)

df <- test[, .(Years = time_length(max(Date) - min(Date), "years"), BeginScore = max(Score), EndScore = min(Score)), by = ID]
```

produces

```
  ID     Years BeginScore EndScore
1  1 0.9993155         70       62
2  2 0.9993155         92       85
3  3 0.9993155         90       82
```

### EDIT TO ADD:

As `min` / `max` will not work if there are several records with the same ID, then the following code can be used instead:

```
test[, .(Years = time_length(Date[.N] - Date[.N - 1], "years"), BeginScore = Score[.N - 1], EndScore = Score[.N]), by = ID]
```

Comment: While I understand it creates the same output as the toy example, since this is taking max/min rather than iteratively calculating, it wouldn't handle, say, instances where the subsequent score in a time series is higher than the previous, correct? Also, when I try to run the above code, I get the error `max is not meaningful for factors`

Comment: You can use position instead of max/min, in a way similar to what @ronak proposed in the dplyr answer. In data.table's case will be using `.N` instead of last and `.N - 1` as the one before, see my edit.

Comment: as for the error related to factors: it will go away with the new code. Please keep in mind that your toy data didn't have factors (it didn't closely represented your real data).